# I can not get Json array from spring rest controller and fill jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, spring-restcontroller

I have this method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateWithParams", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ResolutionDto> updateWithParams() {
        List<ResolutionDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Resolution> resolutions = resolutionService.findAll();
        for (Resolution resolution : resolutions) {
            list.add(new ResolutionDto(resolution.getId(), resolution.getName(), resolution.getStatus(), resolution.getDateCreated(), resolution.getUserName()));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

It is ResolutionDto

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResolutionDto {
    public Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer status;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private String userName;
}
```

And on Client side I want get this array like JSON array and fill jQuery DataTable.

```
function loadTable() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/updateWithParams',
            success: function (data) {
                var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
                var datatable = $('#example').dataTable().api();
                datatable.fnAddData(jsdata);
            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

But it not work. I thik problem in this line `var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);`

but I do not understand how fix it

Comment: If you could add in the DataTable initialization javascript that might be helpful as well.  Just in case the issue is in the DataTable options.

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget about the *Ajax* stuff for a moment as yours looks fine.

There's nothing wrong with the *`JSON.parse(data)`*, its just redundant as *`dataType: "json"`* indicates that the type of data that you're expecting back from the server is JSON.

Now put this in your *controller* method (just before the *iteration* part):

```
if (resolutions .isEmpty()) {
System.out.print("The resolutions list is empty!");
}
```

If so, that's the problem, the DTO's properties are not being assigned with any values, therefore the *list* is literally empty. If that is the case then there's nothing people can do as you didn't include your *service*, so nobody can't afford to see how the data initialized or constructed on which parts of your codes.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` is not needed anymore, because it was automatically parsed.
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "url",
type: "get|post",
contentType: "application/json",
success: function(data) {
// try printing, to test
data.foreach(function(obj, index)) {
console.log(obj.name);
}
}
    });
```